# How can I programmatically add text as if it was copied to be pasted?

Tags: ruby, windows, copy-paste

I would like to write a ruby program preferably, that can take a string object and write it's contents to the clipboard in windows to be pasted.

Easiest test case, a command that can be run globally like cat, but instead of stdout it writes to the clipboard, for things like ssh keys.

Comment: https://github.com/envygeeks/clippy

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/85/1694/README.html) gem.
I haven't personally tested.

[Here](http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/) is the page of the project that implements the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/), but I think this would also work if running that interpreter (untested):

```
include System::Windows::Forms
Clipboard.SetText 'foo'
```